# How to enable Angular $http redirect on CORS

Tags: angularjs, express, cors

I have a node/express aplication with CORS enabled

When I do POST `/login` to my app does a redirect to `/failure` or `/success`

but always a i get a

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://exampledomain.com/login. The request was redirected to 'http://exampledomain.com/success', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

the `$http` do two requests to the server

### OPTIONS request

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://otherdomain.com
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,PATCH,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, content-type
Connection: keep-alive
```

### Options response

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://otherdomain.com
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,PATCH,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, content-type
Connection: keep-alive
```

### POST request

```
POST /admin/login HTTP/1.1
Host: exampledomain.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 43
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://otherdomain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2267.0 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://otherdomain.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: es-419,es;q=0.8
```

### POST response

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Vary: X-HTTP-Method-Override, Origin, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://otherdomain.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Location: /success
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 45
set-cookie: cookie-data; Path=/; HttpOnly
Connection: keep-alive
```

I think the headers are correct but something is missing about the `Location` header. Can help me with this

I'm doing the request with $http like follows

```
$http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
$http.post('http://exampledomain/login', {
  username: 'user',
  password: 'pass'
}).success(...).error(...)
```

but the success is never called

Comment: The issue is with redirecting. A preflight request is sent to make sure the request can go ahead but you redirect so the preflight isn't verified anymore. I don't quite understand why you are doing the redirect but why not make a separate request in the success handler?

Answer (score -1):

CORS is not enabled for `http://exampledomain.com`, thus no requests can be made to it. In fact the browser does a preflight check and since it fails the requests are not actually sent to the server at all.

The only way to change this is to enable CORS on the server for your domain.